# Regarding Cassandra Table Size

Tags: cassandra

How to calculate the total size of a keyspace in cassandra?
I have tried the nodetool cfstats and nodetool tablestats command. It is giving a lot of information, but I am not sure which field provides the exact information.
Can anybody suggest any method to find out the size of a keyspace and a table in Cassandra?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"nodetool tablestats" replaces the older command "nodetool cfstats". In other words both are the same. Output of this command lists the size of each of the tables within a keyspace.

Amongst the output, you are looking for **"Space used (total)"** value. Its the Total number of bytes of disk space used by SSTables belonging to this table, including obsolete SSTables waiting to be GCd.

Since there could be multiple tables within a keyspace, you need to **sum up "Space used (total)" for all tables belonging to a keyspace** to get size occupied by keyspace.

Another alternative if you have SSH access to the nodes, is to get to Cassandra Data directory and issue "du -h" to get the size of each keyspace directory. Again sum up the directory size on all nodes for that keyspace (ignoring the snapshot sizes).

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was very helpful  :-)